# Need help finding the error in my Visual Basic code

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim salesAmt As Double
    Const stateRate As Double = 0.025
    Const countyRate As Double = 0.005
    Const cityRate As Double = 0.0025
    Dim stateTax As Double
    Dim countyTax As Double
    Dim cityTax As Double



    Public Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles entryLabel.Click
        salesAmt = Convert.ToDouble(salesAmtTextBox.Text)

    End Sub

    Public Sub subButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles subButton.Click

        stateTax = stateRate * salesAmt
        countyTax = countyRate * salesAmt
        cityTax = cityRate * salesAmt

        stateLabel.Text = stateTax.ToString("C2")
        countyLabel.Text = countyTax.ToString("C2")
        cityLabel.Text = cityTax.ToString("C2")
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm meant to make a small application that displays tax rates for state/county/city, has a box to input the quarterly sales amount, and a submit button to calculate that amount and display all three tax values. Every time I hit submit I'm getting $0.00 in all the text boxes, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think here is the problem.. You have to make it clear. Besides, you can remove the Label1.Click. It is no function if you don't click it.

```
Public Sub subButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles subButton.Click

stateTax = stateRate * salesAmtTextBox.Text
countyTax = countyRate * salesAmtTextBox.Text
cityTax = cityRate * salesAmtTextBox.Text

stateLabel.Text = stateTax.ToString("C2")
countyLabel.Text = countyTax.ToString("C2")
cityLabel.Text = cityTax.ToString("C2")
End Sub
```

Comment: I just realized my mistake, thanks! Yeah, idk why that was there, I think I just wasn't reading it properly and just stuck it in the place I thought I was working in (Gosh I feel stupid)

Comment: That's great. You can also declare it in the `subButton_Click` . Example: `Dim salesAmt = salesAmtTextBox.Text`. Click 'tick' on the left corner if the question is answered.